# minicart mixin doesn't read customerData

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

i'm trying to create custom popup modal when click on "Go to checkout" button from Minicart.

i have write this code to open custom modal if the guest checkout is disabled, and redirect the customer to checkout if the customer is logged in.

**this is my minicart mixin**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/authentication-popup',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function ($, authenticationPopup, customerData) {
    'use strict';
    
    return function (Component) {
        return Component.extend({

            /**
             * @override
             */
            getCartParam: function (name) {
                var self = this;

               if (name === 'possible_onepage_checkout') {
                    $('#top-cart-btn-checkout').click(function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        var customer = customerData.get('customer');
                        if (!customer().firstname) {
                            $('.mobile-sendotp-popup').modal('openModal');
                            console.log("hello guest open poup");
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            console.log("hello customer checkout");
                            location.href = window.checkout.checkoutUrl;
                        }
                    });
               }
                return this._super(name);
            },
        });
    }
});
```

**it's working fine when i'm browsing as guest, but when trying to go to checkout after logged in, then the button is not clickable at all and print this in log**

```
                    hello guest open poup
```

so after lot of investigation i see that it doesn't read customerData at all!

kindly advise.

Comment: I've tested your code, and it works as expected for both guest and logged in customer. Let's check the Console tab and share related logs in your post.

Comment: @TuVan thanks, i've debugging the problem, and i discover that the issue in Browser Local Storage.
it doesn't clear the local storage (customer) after logout?
any advise?